# Navigation, not working from Pulled functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I will try to explain this as best I can, I'm still new and have a hard time understanding the terminology.

I am working on a react native project. I have created two files. One Header.js and one footer.js.

I have successfully pulled them in to my Home Screen. However the buttons, inside footer.js, no longer fires. I get; undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') for the error.

How do I bring back the functionality?

Any help is very appreciated. Here is my project to help;
App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import TabNavigator from "./assets/component/TabNavigator";
import {StackNavigation} from "./assets/component/StackNavigation";


export default function App() {
    return (
       <StackNavigation/>
    );
}
```

StackNavigation.js;

```js
import React from 'react';
import { HomeScreen} from "../Screens/HomeScreen";
import LayoutProps from "../Screens/Layout Props";
import SampleViewProps from "../Screens/SampleViewProps";
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
// import ShareExample from "./assets/component/SBShare";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export function StackNavigation() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Layout Props" component={LayoutProps} />
                <Stack.Screen name="View Props" component={SampleViewProps} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

HomeScreen.js;

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Button, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import HeaderSB from "../component/SBHeader";
import FooterSB from "../component/SBFooter";

// import ShareExample from "./assets/component/SBShare";

export function HomeScreen({navigation}) {

    const receiveValue = (value) => {
        console.log("value received from B", value)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <HeaderSB receiveValue={receiveValue}>
                    </HeaderSB>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.mainContent}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonBox}>
                        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Layout Props')} title="Layout Props"/>
                        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('View Props')} title="View Style Props"/>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View styles={styles.footerContainer}>
                    <FooterSB receiveValue={receiveValue}>
                    </FooterSB>
                </View>

            </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
    headerContainer: {

    },
    mainContent: {

    },
    buttonBox: {}
    ,
    footerContainer: {

    },
});
```

Footer.js;

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
import {AntDesign, Feather} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {StackNavigation} from "./StackNavigation";

const FooterSB = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <>
            {/* Bottom App Navigation */}
            <View style={footerStyle.navCon}>
                <View style={footerStyle.navBar}>

                    {/* Home Button */}
                    <TouchableOpacity style={footerStyle.home} onPress={() =>
                        navigation.navigate('Home')}
                    >
                        {/* Icon */}
                        <AntDesign name="home" size={50} color="white"/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    {/* Navigation Divider */}
                    <View style={footerStyle.navDivider}/>

                    {/* Setting Button */}
                    <TouchableOpacity style={footerStyle.settings} onPress={() =>
                        navigation.navigate('Layout Props')}
                    >
                        {/* Icon */}
                        <Feather name="settings" size={50} color="white"/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </>

    );
}

const footerStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    navCon: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    },
    navBar: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#808080",
        width: 500,
        height: 50,
    },
    home: {
        // paddingHorizontal: 55,
    },
    navDivider: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        width: 4,
        height: 50,
    },
    settings: {
        // marginRight: 107,
        // paddingHorizontal: 55,
    },
});

export default FooterSB;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigation as default prop you should add it as `<Stack.Screen>` but as FooterSB is custom and individual component it doesn't get wrapped with navigation prop automatically.

You need to pass navigation as prop to that so change below

```
<FooterSB receiveValue={receiveValue}>
</FooterSB>
```

to

```
<FooterSB receiveValue={receiveValue} navigation={navigation}>
</FooterSB>
```

Same way you can pass navigation to header too.

Comment: Didn't work. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: what is the error now? remove spaces from the name in the Stack.Screen i.e. change 'Layout Props' to 'LayoutProps'

Comment: still no. The error is "can't find variable navigation. navigation in the "navigation.navigate" has the squiggly line under it and want me to import NavigationActions as navigate from react-navigation. Which I don't use, but have imported it, and now the errors are gone, but there is no action on button press.

Comment: You have to pass navigation in both of your component FooterSB and HeaderSB, I just shared example for FooterSB. Update your code what did you update after my suggestions.